# Obter valor da URL em um DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, querystring, asp.net-mvc-routing

Em minha aplicação eu possuo um `DropDownList` que filtra os dados da pesquisa. Ao filtrar, ele recupera o valor da `QueryString` e deixa salvo o valor no próprio `DropDownList` (para que ao mudar de página, a opção do filtro continue). Porém, eu alterei a rota em meu `RouteConfig.cs`, para mostrar as rotas mais amigáveis.

Antes de mudar a rota, eu possuía essa `URl`:

> ~/Index?ano=2015&filial=1&tipoPrestacao=2

Utilizo o `Request[" "]` em cada `DropDownList`, recuperando assim o valor.

Ao mudar a rota, minha `URL` mudou para:

> ~/Index/2015/1/=2

Porém, desta forma o `Request[" "]` não consegue recuperar o valor, retornando assim o `DropDownList` sempre para o primeiro valor.

Meu `DropDownList` está da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                            Tipo Prestação de Contas:
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlPrestacao", new SelectList(ViewBag.TipoPrestacao, "TipoPrestacaoId", "Descricao", Request["tipoPrestacao"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            Ano:
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlAno", new SelectList(ViewBag.Ano, "anoVigencia", "anoVigencia", Request["ano"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            Filial:
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlFilial", new SelectList(ViewBag.Filiais, "value", "text", Request["filial"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
```

A minha rota foi alterada para:

```
//Antes
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Cliente", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            //Depois
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ListaClientes",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{ano}/{filial}/{tipoPrestacao}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Cliente", action = "Index", ano = "", filial = "", tipoPrestacao = "" }
            );
```

### Edit

Meu `Controller` está da seguinte forma:

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(string ano, string filial, string tipoPrestacao)
        {

            var tipoPrestacoes = new List<SelectListItem>();
            tipoPrestacoes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mensal", Value = "1" });
            tipoPrestacoes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Quadrimestral", Value = "2" });
            tipoPrestacoes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mensal + M13 M14", Value = "3" });

            ViewBag.Tipo = tipoPrestacoes;

            var anoPrestacao = _clienteRepository.ObterTodos()
                .GroupBy(c => c.AnoVigencia)
                .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(items => new ClienteViewModel() { ClienteId = items.ClienteId, AnoVigencia = items.AnoVigencia }).ToList();

            ViewBag.Ano = anoPrestacao;

             var prestacaoTipo = _pprestacaoRepository.ObterTodos()
                .GroupBy(c => c.Descricao)
                .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(items => new TipoPrestacaoViewModel() { TipoPrestacaoId = items.TipoPrestacaoId, Descricao = items.Descricao }).ToList();

            ViewBag.TipoPrestacao = prestacaoTipo;

               return View(_clienteRepository.ObterTodos());
        }
```

Comment: Você pode colocar também na sua pergunta como está a *Action* do *Controller*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez editei a resposta com a Action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está tudo certo. Apenas use [`RouteData.Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.routing.routedata(v=vs.118).aspx) ao invés de `Request`:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    Tipo Prestação de Contas:
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlPrestacao", new SelectList(ViewBag.TipoPrestacao, "TipoPrestacaoId", "Descricao", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["tipoPrestacao"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    Ano:
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlAno", new SelectList(ViewBag.Ano, "anoVigencia", "anoVigencia", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ano"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    Filial:
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlFilial", new SelectList(ViewBag.Filiais, "value", "text", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["filial"]), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda.