# @Html.ActionLink e Url.Action não estão pegando a rota da anotação do controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o seguinte método no controle:

```
[Route("video/categoria/{categoria}/{page?}/{sort?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string categoria, int? page, string sort)
{
...  
}
```

Meu RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Categoria", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

}
```

Meu URL.Action:

```
Url.Action("Index","Video", new { categoria = @Request.QueryString["categoria"], page = 5, sort = ViewBag.CurrentSort})
```

Resultado do URL.Action : 
`http://localhost:59278/Video?categoria=desenho&page=4`

Resultado esperado do Url.Action: 
`http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/desenho/4`

Meu Html.ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Teste", "Index", "Video", new { categoria = @Request.QueryString["categoria"], page = 1, sort = "teste" }, null))
```

Resultado do Html.ActionLink:

```
http://localhost:59278/Video?categoria=desenho&page=1&sort=teste
```

Resultado esperado no Html.ActionLink:

```
http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/desenho/1/teste
```

Como fazer para transformar o resultado no resultado esperado?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Ele funciona da seguinte foram:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Teste", "Index", "Video", new { categoria = 1, page = 1, sort = 1 }, null)
```

Então acredito que reduzir a margem de locais onde poderiam ser o problema ao quarto parâmetro do construtor.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Depois de verificar novas possibilidades eu vi que o problema se trata do `@Request.QueryString["categoria"]`, quando usado ele não faz a URL de forma correta, mas quando eu retiro ele e jogo uma string ou int no lugar ele funciona normalmente.

Qual o motivo disso?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Uma outra tentativa, não funcionou, mas descobri que na verdade não se pode usar nenhuma variável no parametro:

```
@{ 
    var cat = @Request.QueryString["categoria"];
}

@Html.ActionLink("Teste", "ConsultaVideo", "Video", new { categoria = cat, page = 1, sort = "teste" }, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes eu achei a solução.

O problema é que o `@Request.QueryString["categoria"]` retorna null, com isso o objeto categoria do construtor recebe null e com isso ele entende que não existe categoria na rota, logo, ele não acha o método no controle.

Não sei como fazer para pegar o valor, isso seria assunto para outra pergunta.

O código que usei para teste é esse:

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente está tudo certo, apenas utilize o [RouteData.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.routing.routedata(v=vs.118).aspx) para recuperar o valor da [querystring](/questions/tagged/querystring) ao invés do `Request`.

Ficaria assim sua variável `cat`:

```
var cat = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["categoria"];
```

Qualquer dúvida, [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68123/20615) pode lhe ajudar melhor.